# Pandas merging on keys - TypeError: unhashable instance

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have two dataframes that i'm trying to merge on key 'Time'. The first dataframe (events) has a set of events with time as below (indexed over Date):

```
             Time                                   Event Importance Actual Forecast Previous
Date                                                                                         
2014-04-04  07:30      EUR German Markit Construction PMI     Medium    NaN      NaN     53.6
2014-04-04  08:10            EUR German Markit Retail PMI     Medium    NaN      NaN     52.1
2014-04-04  08:10         EUR Euro-Zone Markit Retail PMI     Medium    NaN      NaN      NaN
2014-04-04  10:00  EUR German Factory Orders n.s.a. (YoY)     Medium    NaN     6.8%     8.4%
2014-04-04  12:30            CAD Net Change in Employment       High    NaN    22.5K    -7.0K
```

and the second one (df1) contains a list of counts with the same time format (indexed over Time - going up to 23:59):

```
        Time  count
00:00  00:00     64
00:01  00:01     25
00:02  00:02     19
00:03  00:03     15
00:04  00:04     20
.
.
07:30  07:30     26
.
.
08:10  08:10     35
```

What i'm looking for is to get

```
Time                                   Event    count
07:30      EUR German Markit Construction PMI    26
08:10            EUR German Markit Retail PMI    35
08:10         EUR Euro-Zone Markit Retail PMI    35
```

I'm trying to merge both these table to get the count next to events table using the below pandas merge function however it throwing a unhashable instance error - can someone advise?

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
events.reset_index(inplace=True)
dfMerged = pd.merge(events, df1,
              left_on=['Time', 'Event'],
              right_on=['Time', 'count'],
              how='inner')
dfMerged.set_index('date', inplace=True)

TypeError: unhashable instance
```

or even if i just do:

```
dfMerged = pd.merge(events, df1,
          on='Time',
          how='inner')
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with you left_on, right_on. If this was a 1:1 merge (let's say), then the merge would only ever happen if the combination of 'Time' and 'Event' in the Events dataframe, exactly matches the combination of 'Time' and 'count' in the other data frame. From what I see above, this is never going to be the case. It looks to me like you are just wanting to merge on 'Time' in both sets. If this is not right, try putting the lef_on syntax in tuples. Lists are not hashable as they are mutable.

Comment: Thanks, both events and df1 have Time column which are of different length - e.g. count is for every min consistently where else events is just unique times. Would you be able to provide a snippet for left_on in tuples?

Comment: I'm prettys sure you don't want to merge on those variables, you just want to merge on Time. Is that not right?

Comment: If it is what you want, try changing the square brackets to round brackets and see what happens.... Not a lot is my guess

Comment: Tried to just merge on Time but getting the same error:

Comment: dfMerged = pd.merge(events, df1,
              left_on=['Time'],
              right_on=['Time'],
              how='inner') -> ie unhashable instance, i'm looking for results like Time, Event, count ie 07:30      EUR German Markit Construction PM   65 (say count at 07:30 in df1 is 65).

Comment: forget left_on right_on, just use on = 'Time', it exists in both dataframes

Comment: if you could supply some data that would help. looking at the above data its not at all clear what it is you actually want to do. In the data supplied I don't see any exampels where Time = Time in both sets....

Comment: thanks, Woody Pride! I've just updated the post with what i'm looking for.

Comment: Your second attempt should have worked, I think: I'd usually write `df1.merge(events, on="Time")` or even `df1.merge(events)` here.  It would help if you could provide a self-contained example (`.to_dict()` can come in handy.)